# Convert string to multidimensional array indexes Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, nested

I have tried multiple ways but this is not working..

I have the following string `hello.my.name.is.jordan`

That when split by `.` produces:

```
myString = ["hello, "my","name","is","jordan"];
```

I am trying to convert it to

```
MyMultiDimensionString["hello"]["my"]["name]["is"]["jordan"]
```

Where `MyMultiDimensionString` is 5

Any suggestions on how to achieve the final bit in Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Is `MyMultiDimensionString` an object?

Comment: @NickParsons nope is an Array

Comment: An array of *what*? What would be the value of `MyMultiDimensionString["hello"]["my"]["name"]["is"]["jordan"]`?

Comment: @VLAZ I have a value defined for that particular multidimensional array

Comment: @Gabs `MyMultiDimensionString["hello"]["my"]["name"]["is"]["jordan"]` is not a valid array. That piece of code will only work for an object like `{"hello":{"my":{"name":{"is":"jordan"}}}}`. Is that what you want? Or do you want to do `MyMultiDimensionString['["hello"]["my"]["name"]["is"]["jordan"]']`?

Comment: @Gabs can you give an example of what `MyMultiDimensionString` looks like please? In your example, is `MyMultiDimensionString` a predefined variable or is there supposed to be an `=` after it?

Comment: @nickzoum or `{"hello":{"my":{"name":{"is":{"jordan":{}}}}}}` - it's completely unclear what the end result is expected to be. All the answers assume it's just `[["hello"],["my"],["name"],["is"],["jordan"]]` which might also be correct.

Comment: @NickParsons 
array["hello"]["my"]["name]["is"]["jordan"] = '5'

I have defined that previously

I just need to convert that string into that multidimensional array

Comment: @Gabs: so, you expect `{"hello":{"my":{"name":{"is":{"jordan":5}}}}}`?

Comment: @Gabs is `array["hello"]["my"]["name]["is"]["jordan"] = '5'` the exact statement you used to define the value?

Comment: @nickzoum

let put it this way..

hello : { my : { name { is : { jordan : 5 } } } }

is an object

I have a string 

hello.my.name.is.jordan


Maybe like this is clearer

PS: Sorry for any misunderstanding

Comment: @Gabs So you used `{ my : { name: { is : { jordan : 5 } } } }` to set the 5, ok

Comment: @Gabs Please post the result of `JSON.stringify(MyMultiDimensionString)` to your question.

Comment: @Gabs So `MyMultiDimensionString` only contains the literal `5`? Are you sure you that you did `JSON.stringify(MyMultiDimensionString)` and not `JSON.stringify(MyMultiDimensionString["hello"]["my"]["name]["is"]["jordan"])`. If `MyMultiDimensionString` is 5 then I fail to see how multidimensional array are involved.

Comment: @Gabs Please post the code all of the code you have currently written

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the splitted string as keys for reducing an object.

```js
const getValue = (object, keys) => keys.reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object);

var string = 'hello.my.name.is.jordan',
    object = { hello: { my: { name: { is: { jordan: 42 } } } } };

console.log(getValue(object, string.split('.')));
```

Comment: This was the correct answer! Thanks Nina I totally overlooked this!

Answer (score 3):

You can split on each '.', and then `reduceRight` it into an object:

```js
const myString = "hello.my.name.is.jordan";

const x = '5'

arr = myString.split('.').reduceRight((a, v) => ({[v]: a}), x)

console.log(arr["hello"]["my"]["name"]["is"]["jordan"])
console.log(arr)
```

> The end result cannot be an array, as there is no such thing as an associative array in javascript. This is what objects are for.

-

> EDIT

I am assuming you already have the object and want to access the value with a string:

```js
const obj = {hello: {my: {name: {is: {jordan: 5}}}}}
const str = 'hello.my.name.is.jordan'

console.log(str.split('.').reduce((a, o) => a[o] || {}, obj))
```

Comment: @kobe thanks for the comment but that is not an option to reverse it... 

Consider value 5 as an X

Comment: @Gabs check my edit

Comment: let put it this way.. hello : { my : { name { is : { jordan : 5 } } } } is an object I have a string hello.my.name.is.jordan Maybe like this is clearer PS: Sorry for any misunderstanding

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: @Gabs Check my edit

Comment: Yeah Kobe that was it!!

Answer (score -2):

Use the `Array.reduce()` method to transform this into a multidimensional array;

```js
const myString = ["hello", "my","name","is","jordan "];

const result = myString.reduce((arr, curr) => {
    return [...arr, [curr]];
}, []);

// result = [["hello"],["my"],["name"],["is"],["jordan "]]
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? @Gabs, you wanted to convert an array to a multidimensional one and this code does EXACTLY that

Comment: I didn't down vote it at all...
But your solution suppose to return this though
Array["hello"]["my"]["name]["is"]["jordan"] 

Thanks for trying anyways

Comment: @StefanN I'm guessing people downvoted because your answer is based on speculation and werent certain what the question was about.

Comment: @StefanN result should be like this


array["hello"]["my"]["name]["is"]["jordan"] = '5'

I have defined that previously

I just need to convert that string into that multidimensional array